# JSDoc importing from another file with webpack/ts alias

Tags: webpack, webstorm, jsdoc

Given:

```
/** @typedef {import('../../../store/modules/TypeA').TypeA} TypeA */  //resolves
/** @typedef {import('@/store/modules/TypeB').TypeB} TypeB */ //any
```

TypeA works, TypeB does not.

Is there a way for my IDE to respect my webpack configuration, or perhaps tsconfig.json with path alias?

Comment: were you able to find workaround for this ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment. No I never did.